# @NotNull validation on collection with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have a problem with clearable exception when I post to my controller - json with nulls.

I`ve set all fields as @NotNull. And it`s work fine (which null values I see nice exception with message: Field error in object '' on field '': rejected value [null]).

Unfortunately collections fields with @NotNull return JsonMappingException.

For example:

```
  @Value
public final class User {

    @NotNull
    private final Integer age; //work fine


    @NotNull
    private final List<Books> books; //doesn`t work
```

I`ve also tried with @Valid and @NotEmpty, but it didn`t help.

My controller method:

```
@Timed
    @ExceptionMetered
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PreAuthorize("@auth.hasAccess(...)")
    void registerUser(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {
        userService.registerUser(user);
    }
```

Do you know what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try both?

```
@NotNull
@Valid
private final List<Books> books;
```

**EDIT**

---

**Spring Version**: 1.4.7.RELEASE

Book:

```
public class Book {

    private String id;
    private String title;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

User:

```
public class User {

    @NotNull
    private int age;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private List<Book> books;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

     public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
     }

     public List<Book> getBooks() {
         return books;
     }

     public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
         this.books = books;
     }

 }
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public User post(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {
    return user;
}
```

Tests:

```
curl -s -XPOST http://localhost:8080/ -d '{"age": 13, "books": [{"id": "test", "title": "test"}]}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" | python -m json.tool

{
  "age": 13,
  "books": [
    {
      "id": "test",
      "title": "test"
    }
   ]
}

curl -s -XPOST http://localhost:8080/ -d '{"age": 13}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" | python -m json.tool

{
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "errors": [...]
}
```

Apparently, nothing wrong...

Comment: Yes, the same result :(

Comment: Could you provide the request body and your Books class as well?

Comment: It is only example. Books class is a normal class with few fields (int, String). I added my requestbody in original post.

Comment: Actually I was asking for the http request body that the client is sending to your backend. Just to make sure that the json format matches your classes.

Comment: the json request is correct. I checked it many times. When I send json with all fields -work fine. - without not-collection field - work fine (validaiton exception with clearable message) - without Set/List/Map - JsonParsingException (without information which field is null - I want to know it).

Comment: I did try to simulate your issue, apparently there's nothing wrong...I have edited my answer.